# Virtual Keyboard on mobile browser hides content instead of pushing it up

Tags: javascript, html, css, chat, mobile-website

I am making a mobile web application (using JavaScript) for chatting, so think of the user interface like Viber or WhatsApp or any other chat application, but in a browser instead.

You can see alive demo here: https://mandarini.github.io/chatsim/

You can access this from your phone. The problem is clearly illustrated.

You can find the code here: https://github.com/mandarini/chatsim

I have an input form box with position fixed that stays at the bottom of the browser window. The messages are above the text box, and they scroll behind it, like the message boxes do in WhatsApp.
When the virtual keyboard on my phone appears, that is when I am about to type something, the text box is indeed pushed up, and is fixed at the bottom of the viewport screen, right above the keyboard as expected.
However, the chat messages are not pushed up. As a result, the latest messages are hidden behind the keyboard.

Image 1: Keyboard is hidden

[image]

Image 2: Keyboard is shown, messages are hidden behind it

[image]

Image 3: Expected result, keyboard is shown, messages are pushed up

[image]

Note 1: One main problem is that there is no javascript event that catches the expanse/collapse of the virtual keyboard.

Note 2: The onfocus event does not necessarily capture the expanse/collapse, since a virtual keyboard can be hidden, but still the text box may remain focused.

Below you can find a simplified version of my code, which mocks the posting of messages.

I want the newly posted messages to appear above the virtual keyboard on mobile devices.

```js
function addMsg(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var message = document.createElement("div");
  var user = document.createElement("p");
  var text = document.createElement("p");
  user.appendChild(document.createTextNode("User"));
  text.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Message message"));
  message.appendChild(user);
  message.appendChild(text);
  message.classList.add("chat-msg");
  document.getElementById("chats").appendChild(message);
  message.scrollIntoView();
  return false;
}
```

```css
.chat-container {}

.chat-messages {
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 66px;
  /* leaves space for input */
}

.chat-form {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  padding: 7px 8px 7px 8px;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 96%;
  padding: 17px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.chat-msg {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 90%;
  clear: both;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.chat-msg p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat" class="chat-container">
  <div id="chats" class="chat-messages">
  </div>
  <form onsubmit="addMsg(event)" class="chat-form">
    <label>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    <input class="hidden" type="submit" value="Post" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the 'focusout' event for this.

```js
document.addEventListener('focusout', e => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

Also sent a PR: https://github.com/mandarini/chatsim/pull/1

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunatelly this does not solve the issue. Scrolling to (0,0) scrolls the window to the top, I want the messages to be scrolled at the bottom. Even If I tell the window to scroll to bottom, it does not see the bottom of the window as the beginning of the virtual keyboard, it does not always detect the existence of the virtual keyboard. The result is that even though there are occasions when the window is shrunk (img 3 of the post) & messages are properly scrolled into view, in most cases the "view", as fas as the DOM is concerned, continues behind the virtual keyboard.